# Improve my question further in askubuntu

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Newbie here as well as Ask Ubuntu. Before posted my first question I have searched a lot in Google but I couldn't find the answer to solve my installation [issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/520718/upgrade-12-to-14-no-public-key-available) problem. So I decided to post, but thought my question is good but today it's seemed I received -1 vote. But I tell clearly

1. What I want to achieve ...!
2. What is the error.
3. Sufficient details for OS I am having.

Well I am aware of how to ask good question in stack-exchange community but I am eager to  know how can I improve my question further here?

Comment: Don't take it too seriously. There are a lot of h8rs out there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To be honest, the question looks good to me. You provided the information you could find and replied quite quickly on requests for additional information. The suggested suspicion about 11.04 proved incorrect. Since there was no additional request for information, there is not much you can be blamed of I think.

Many times, downvotes are correct, sometimes they are not. We've all been there.

Comment: To extend this answer: It looks like some users find it funny to downvote simply to do this. Especially in the last days I found many downvotes where no reason can be found.